# Get Server side values to Client side

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here i'm going to get Server side values to client side.

aspx

```
<a href="#" class="alert-link">Welcome <%=GetUserName();%></a> <-- problem in here
```

aspx.cs

```
public string GetUserName()
{
    string name;
    MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser();
    name = usr.UserName; //<-- Correct names come to here
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspx markup is invalid. You should not have a semicolon inside the ERB tag.

```
<a href="#" class="alert-link">
    Welcome <%= GetUserName() %>
</a>
```

Additionally consider checking for `null`.

```
public string GetUserName()
{
    var user = Membership.GetUser();
    if(user == null)
    {
        return "Anonymous";
    }

    return user.UserName;
}
```